# Background Image height and overlay content overflows and repeats

Tags: html, ios, css

I'm trying to fit the background image onto a iPad screen with a frameless browser.

The height of the image fits perfectly however, the width does not and the image repeats itself which makes the page scrollable horizontally. (I want it to be single page with the no repeat of the image). May I know how do I fit it the image to the width?

```
body {
background-image: url("main.jpg");
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

At the same time, I have a overlay content where you click on the box and the content will appear. However, the overlay box is way too big off the screen on the iPad. Would the overlay be affecting the background? And how would I make it fit within the screen?

```
HTML
<!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <img src="tyedit.jpg" />
            <div id="imagine">
                <span id="clicked">0</span><br/>
                <span id="word">VOTES</span>
            </div>
    </div>
    </div>

CSS
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
display: none; /* Hidden by default */
position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%; /* Full width */
height: 100%; /* Full height */
overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
position: relative;  
margin: auto;
padding: 0;  
width: 70%;
height: 100%;
-webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
-webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
animation-name: animatetop;
animation-duration: 0.4s
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to dismiss the repeat. You need to set `no-repeat` refer this link

[w3schools-backgroundrepeat-property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp)

[full tutorial for background](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_background-size)

```
div {
    background-image:url(smiley.gif);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

Try this and reply what problem you still encounter. I will reply the answer here

**UPDATE**

Overflow issue for iOS

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto
```

Refer here [webkit-overflow-scrolling](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_background-size)

Comment: Thank you, the background-repeat worked! However, the overflow is now vertical and the image width exceed to the right but without any overflow.

Comment: may you post a snippet ? so i can understand clearly @user2728875

Comment: This is a screenshot on the iPad frameless browser: http://imgur.com/OYZnjNb I managed to fix the width issue but the background image is still allowed to scroll down vertically and not within the height of just the screen. @AKZhang

Comment: please post it here. i can't open that link due to AV @user2728875

Comment: I've managed to fit the image within the screen. Would you know how to prevent vertical scrolling as there are some white excess spaces which allows overflow. (I've already tried overflow:hidden) but it does not seem to work on the iPad. @AKZhang

Comment: Hi @user2728875 great that you have solved it. as for overflow issue in iOS. I have updated my answer